# Published Power BI report not refreshing

Tags: ms-access, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

When I try to refresh the dataset, (manually or automatically), I get the following error:

**Failure details: The last refresh attempt failed because of an internal service error. This is usually a transient issue. If you try again later and still see this message, contact support. 
Microsoft Access: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. The 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine 2010 Access Database Engine OLEDB provider may be required to read this type of file. To download the client software, visit the following site: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=285987.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: Track Changes.**

Answer (score 5):

Try refreshing the report and check again. If you are still facing this error then, I would recommend you to log a ticket at https://community.powerbi.com with the following details.

- Activity Id
- Request Id
- Cluster Uri
- Correlation Id
- Refresh Time

You can get the above list of details by following the below steps:

1. Refresh the dataset, by clicking the "Refresh Now" or "Schedule
   Refresh" option.
2. Once you see the below error click on "Show
   technical details".

[image: Error Picture]
[image: Technical Details]